# AttributeError: module 'pyximport.pyximport' has no attribute 'get_distutils_extension'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation

I am struggling with the below error: `AttributeError: module 'pyximport.pyximport' has no attribute 'get_distutils_extension'` on executing the code below:

```
import warnings   
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, execute, Aer
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance


(qiskit_0.23.6) m99693@alveo:~/RESEARCH_WORK/code-main$ python testing.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, execute, Aer
  File "/home/m992c693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.23.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from qiskit.providers.aer import Aer
  File "/home/m992c693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.23.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/aer/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .aerprovider import AerProvider
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.23.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/aer/aerprovider.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .backends.qasm_simulator import QasmSimulator
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.23.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/aer/backends/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .pulse_simulator import PulseSimulator
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.23.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/aer/backends/pulse_simulator.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ..pulse.controllers.pulse_controller import pulse_controller
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.23.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/aer/pulse/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .qutip_extra_lite.cy import pyxbuilder as pbldr
  File "/home/m99693/anaconda3/envs/qiskit_0.23.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/aer/pulse/qutip_extra_lite/cy/pyxbuilder.py", line 55, in <module>
    OLD_EXT = pyximport.pyximport.get_distutils_extension
AttributeError: module 'pyximport.pyximport' has no attribute 'get_distutils_extension'
```

Before executing this: I first created a new conda env, installed the below packages:

```
|  python  |  3.7.4  |
|  qiskit  |  0.23.6  |
| qiskit-aer | 0.7.5 |
| qiskit-aqua | 0.8.2 |
| numpy | 1.19.1 |
| scipy | 1.6.1 |
| matplotlib | 3.4.2 |
| tqdm | 4.60.0 |
```

I am getting this error on my **ubuntu lab system** but **no error** with my **windows laptop**. This might be some operating system related error. Please help me in resolving this error.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you need to install cython.
Since, I am using python 3.7.4, I need to install cython compatible with it.
I installed `pip install cython==0.29` and this resolved the problem.